# Xamarin form 4.3 Label using sans-serif front

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building a Android and iOS app and  wanted to use sans-serif front on a label but I dont see it on the http://iosfonts.com/. I see the front on https://fonts.google.com/?query=sans+serif but I am not sure what to use in the FontFamily tag?

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Text="TestFrontFamily" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" TextColor="White" FontFamily="sans-serif"></Label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you should never change the font in your app. Use the system default font. This is what people are used to on their phone, and opening an app that uses a different font is jarring.

With that out of the way, you need to download the font file, either otf or ttf, and save it somewhere in each android and iOS project. Then the font family points at that file. For example:

Font file placed in Fonts folder:

iOS: `FontAwesome5ProLight`

Android: `Fonts/fa5-pro-light-300.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight`

For iOS you simply need the font family name to be the name of the font to use. For Android, you need to include the path relative to the android csproj file as well as the font file name followed by # and the font name.

[See Xamarin Font Documentation for further information.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts)

Comment: for iOS where do I download the front file?

Comment: it can be any font file you find anywhere. just has to be otf or ttf. maybe others but i'm only familiar with those two.

[DaFont](https://www.dafont.com/) is a pretty well known font resource.